# Using xmlpeek in Nant script gives odd error

Tags: nant

As part of a CI process I am trying to create a buildlabel which consists of the content of an xml element within an xml structure. For this purpose I am using nant and xmlpeek. My problem is that I get an odd error stating:

> "Nodeindex '0' is out of range"

This is only the case if the xml file I am xmlpeeking contains a namespace definition in the root node.

Removing the namespace from the xml file gives me the output I expect.

The nant target that generates the error can be boild down to:

```
    <target name="TDSLabel">
            <property name="element" value=""/>
            <echo message="Getting element" />
            <xmlpeek file="C:\xxx\test1.xml" xpath="//Project/PropertyGroup/ProductVersion" property="element"/>
            <echo message="The found element value was: ${element}" />
    </target>
```

and the test1.xml file looks like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already gave the right hint yourself. It's about the namespace. This should fix it:

```
<target name="TDSLabel">
  <property name="element" value=""/>
  <echo message="Getting element" />
  <xmlpeek
    file="C:\xxx\test1.xml"
    xpath="//x:Project/x:PropertyGroup/x:ProductVersion"
    property="element"
    verbose="true">
    <namespaces>
      <namespace prefix="x" uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" />
    </namespaces>
  </xmlpeek>
  <echo message="The found element value was: ${element}" />
</target>
```

Comment: As stated below the same problem might occur when using xmlpoke ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584766/nant-xmlpoke-and-unique-nodes). Strangely I didn't get any google hits directly on the errormessage combined with neither xmlpeek or nant. Thanks for your answer, now other people might not get stuck with that odd errormessage

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar problem and the anwser to my problem here: [XmlPoke and unique nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584766/nant-xmlpoke-and-unique-nodes). The problem was that I did not include the namespace definition within the xmlpeek element and afterwards omitted the necessary reference to the namespace in my xpath statement:

```
<xmlpeek file="C:\xxx\test1.xml" xpath="//x:Project/x:PropertyGroup/x:ProductVersion" property="element">
    <namespaces>
        <namespace prefix="x" uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" />
    </namespaces>
</xmlpeek>
```